# Auto-sliding not working after clicking the controls

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

In the boxslider, the autosliding works fine the first time. But when we click on the controls (left and right arrow), then auto sliding is not working. Here is my code:

```
<ul id="slider-assocoates">
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/abcdef.png" /></a>
    </li>
     <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/abc.png" /></a>
     </li>
</ul>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="go-prev-assocoates" class="left-arrow">Prev</a>
        <a href="#" id='go-next-assocoates' class="right-arrow">Next</a>
    </nav>
```

---

```
$(function(){
  var slider = $('#slider-assocoates').bxSlider({
    controls: false,
    auto: true,
    pause: 6000
  });

  $('#go-prev-assocoates').click(function(){
    slider.goToPreviousSlide();
    return false;
  });

  $('#go-next-assocoates').click(function(){
    slider.goToNextSlide();
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem; I was facing the same issue with one of my projects:

`slider.startShow();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickNextBind = function(e){
            // if auto show is running, stop it
            var x = 0; 
            if (slider.settings.auto) x = 1;
            if(x == 1) el.stopAuto();
            el.goToNextSlide();
            if(x == 1) el.startAuto();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    var slider = $('#slider-assocoates').bxSlider({
    controls: false,
    auto: true,
    pause: 6000
});

$('#go-prev-assocoates a, #go-next-assocoates a').click(function(e){
    var i = $(this).index();
    slider.goToSlide(i);
    slider.stopAuto();
    restart=setTimeout(function(){
        slider.startAuto();
    },500);
    return false;
});
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most elegant solution that solves the problem for bxSlider 4.1.1. by editing the **jquery.bxslider.js** file, and adding the two lines shown below. then head towards this link [jscompressor](http://jscompressor.com/), to compress it. (include shrink variables) and now it works as its supposed to without extra coding to make a work-around. ( [Thnx to Freelancerrs for this solution](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/issues/16) )

```
....

var clickNextBind = function(e){
    // if auto show is running, stop it
    if (slider.settings.auto) el.stopAuto();


    el.goToNextSlide();
    e.preventDefault();

    el.startAuto();   // ---------------JUST ADD THIS LINE

}

/**
 * Click prev binding
 *
 * @param e (event) 
 *  - DOM event object
 */
var clickPrevBind = function(e){
    // if auto show is running, stop it
    if (slider.settings.auto) el.stopAuto(); 
    el.goToPrevSlide();
    e.preventDefault();

    el.startAuto();   // ---------------JUST ADD THIS LINE

}

...
```